# How to ignore last url part with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to use the react router to show a page according to the first part of the URL, because the last part of the URL is holding an ID. How can I read out the last part, now I'm using string.split("/").pop()

URL
http://localhost:3003/profile/313a2333

Router

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile/>} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#reading-url-params

Comment: This is pretty much the first thing shown in guides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `Route` like the following:

```
<Route path="/profile/:user_id">
```

Then you can get 2nd parameter in `Profile` component.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const params: any = useParams();
const user_id = params.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the second path segment and only want to match according to the first segment then use a `"*"` wildcard matcher.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/profile/*" element={<Profile/>} />
</Routes>
```

If you *do* need to capture this second path segment value, then provide a param name for it.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/profile/:id" element={<Profile/>} />
</Routes>
```

Use the `useParams` hook to access route path params in the routed components.

```
const { id } = useParams();
```